# "Most Popular Posts" widget w/ Google Analytics data & Google Client JavaScript library

Tags: google-analytics, google-client

Is it possible to use the **Google Analytics API** and the **Google Client JavaScript library**, to access data about the most popular items on my site (most visits), and display that in a widget? I need a "Most Popular" pages widget, that would normally require server-side code to built, but I'm wondering if I can do it all on the front-end.

My main concerns are:

1. Is this kind of data available from the Google Analytics API?
2. Will I need visitors to authorise? In the documentation it says "*If the application needs access to the user's personal information, it opens a session with a Google auth server. The auth server opens a dialog box which prompts the user to authorize the use of personal information.*"

Is anyone using this approach?

Comment: I was thinking about a similar thing (building an "People who bought this also bought" widget from GA transaktion data. My idea was to have a Google Apps script as intermediate step to fetch the data from GA.  This way I could authenticate the script to access GA and make the scripts output public (this is stuff I'm going to display on the website anyway, so no privacy concerns here). If you're using the JavaScript API your sites' visitors would need to have access to your GA account, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://popularposts.benguild.com/ ... that's why I built this.  It just receives data from Google Analytics scheduled emails and reminds you to extend them before they stop working after a year.